# Phonegap cordova Build error

Tags: android, cordova

i need some help or suggestions. When i tried to build my phonegap application via cmd line i am having the error as shown below.

```
c:\myapplication>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova platform add --save android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova platform add --save android'
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Running command: c:\myapplication\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

Running: c:\myapplication\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b 


    c:\myapplication\platforms\android\build.gradleDorg.gradle.daemon=true

events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
 Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
      at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
      at child_process.js:1144:20
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

 ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:     

      c:\myapplication\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed    
      with exit code 1
      You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

      Error: c:\myapplication\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command   
      failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone   


  (C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\c
   ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
      at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)


    c:\myapplication>
```

All tools required are correct but cannot figure out what might be the cause of this. Please help. Ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use command line I recommend you to use this documentation and follow steps

[Cordova Command Line Interface](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)

 1. Download and install Node.js
 2. Download and install a git client.
And be sure you add them to Path in windows
 3. Install the cordova 
`npm install -g cordova`
 4. Create app folder 
`cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`
`cd hello`
 5. Add Platforms
`cordova platform add android`
 6. Build App
`cordova build`
 7. Run app
`cordova emulate android`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already installed everything before now apart from setting Path for node.js and git client. Please can you give me a clue on which file to set to path? I tried setting C:\Program Files\nodejs path but did not show anything when i type nodejs on the command line. Thanks

Comment: You will not need to type nodejs on command line you will use instead npm "Nodejs package manager".  
To be sure all paths correct check  
JAVA_HOME  
, "Directory to ant"\apache-ant\bin  
, "Directory to AndroidSDK"\platform-tools  
, "Directory to AndroidSDK"\tools  
, "Directory to git"\bin  
, "Directory to nodejs folder"\nodejs\

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have solved the problem. I removed npm folder in my app data, uninstall nodejs, cordova and phonegap and reinstall everything again. It worked for me. Thanks a lot for your recommendations